# CakePHP 3 Custom helper not working

Tags: cakephp, helper

Hello i am trying to implement a helper extends the Html helper.
I created based on the documentation the below empty custom helper

```
<?php
namespace App\View\Helper;

use Cake\View\Helper;
use Cake\View\Helper\HtmlHelper;
use Cake\View\View;

/**
 * MyHtml helper
 */
class MyHtmlHelper extends HtmlHelper
{
    public function __construct(View $view, $config = []) {
        parent::__construct($view, $config);
    }
/**
 * Default configuration.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_defaultConfig = [];
}
```

I load both of them on AppController but when i use them on the view I receive the expected result from Html helper but not from custom helper why ? (the second helper doesn't return an error but just an empty result)

```
<?php echo $this->Html->tag('div','oti na einai2'); ?>
<?php echo $this->MyHtml->tag('div','oti na einai'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You broke it by overriding the parents default settings.

```
protected $_defaultConfig = [];
```

[See the API documentation.](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.View.Helper.HtmlHelper.html#$_defaultConfig)

Merge whatever you need in the constructor for example instead of overriding the whole property with an empty array.